# After installing expo navegation happened this with my app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Missing package "metro" in the project at /home/diego/projetosweb/nlw/plantmaneger. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the message. Check your package.json file and make sure it has `"react-native"` as one of the dependencies. If it doesn't, open command prompt (or terminal on macOS) and run `npm install react-native` or `yarn add react-native`. If it is there, run `yarn` or `npm install`.